# como obtener el valor de una posicion de un jsonarray?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

una pregunta algo sencilla para muchos, pero a mi no me sale, resulta que quiero obtener una posición de un jsonarray proveniente de un response de un api:

```
JSONArray answers = jsonObject.getJSONArray("answer");
=>[["bogota","cali","medellin","Tunja"],["Santander","Tolima","Risaralda","Quindio"],["false"]]
```

si pongo answer.get(0)

```
=> ["bogota","cali","medellin","Tunja"]
```

pero yo quiero obtener

```
=>Bogota 
=> cali,
=> medellin
```

... por separado

agradezco  su orientacion, gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes hacer lo siguiente:

1. Obtener el `JSONArray` que está en la posición `0` de `answers`
2. Leer en un `for` los elementos de ese `JSONArray`

Veamos un ejemplo. Aquí voy a usar un `StringBuilder` para concatenar los valores dentro del `for` más un salto de línea. Luego, a la salida del `for`, mostraremos todo.

```
        JSONArray indexZero = answers.getJSONArray(0);
        StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < indexZero.length(); ++i) {
            String s = indexZero.getString(i)+System.getProperty("line.separator");
            sb.append(s);
        }
        System.out.println(sb);
```

**Salida:**

```
bogota
cali
medellin
Tunja
```

Comment: muchas gracias!!